# Rendering Binary Files with DD4T.RestService.WebApi

Tags: web8, dxa, dd4t, sdl-tridion, cil

We are using `DD4T.RestService.WebApi` to share the content to external application as a service.

SDL Web 8.5 has been configured to publish content and images to Broker DB. can someone guide on using the `BinaryDistributionModule` to get the binary assets from Broker DB using `DD4T.RestService.WebApi`. `RestServices` is using CIL provider to get the content.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something similar as below;

`http://myurl/binary/GetBinaryByUri/{publicationId:int}/{id:int}`

Example: `http://myurl/binary/GetBinaryByUri/5/445`

Comment: Yes & able to get it as byte stream. But it doesn't download the file to web server file system to leverage caching.